# Reading a komoot xml file (gpx) with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe, gpx

I want to read a xml file generated by komoot into a DataFrame. Here is the structure of the xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="https://www.komoot.de" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <name>Title</name>
    <author>
      <link href="https://www.komoot.de">
        <text>komoot</text>
        <type>text/html</type>
      </link>
    </author>
  </metadata>
  <trk>
    <name>Title</name>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="60.126749" lon="4.250254">
        <ele>455.735013</ele>
        <time>2023-08-20T17:42:34.674Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="60.126580" lon="4.250247">
        <ele>455.735013</ele>
        <time>2023-08-20T17:42:36.695Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="60.126484" lon="4.250240">
        <ele>455.735013</ele>
        <time>2023-08-20T17:44:15.112Z</time>
      </trkpt>
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

I tried this code:

```
pd.read_xml('testfile.gpx',xpath='./gpx/trk/trkseg')
```

But somehow it seems there are problems with my `xpath`. Namely, I get this `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: xpath does not return any nodes. Be sure row level nodes are in xpath. If document uses namespaces denoted with xmlns, be sure to define namespaces and use them in xpath.
```

I tried a lot but no xpath I chose worked out.

Comment: What is the expected output should look like?

Comment: @shaikmoeed I want a table with a row for each `trkpt`. I have not much experience with `pd.read_xml`. So, maybe after fixing the `xpath` I still have to do some adjustments but the goal is to have four columns: lat, lon, ele, time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the `ValueError` *guidelines*, you need to pass a `namespace` to [`read_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) :

```py
df = (
    pd.read_xml(
        "testfile.gpx",
        xpath=".//doc:trkseg/doc:trkpt",
        namespaces={"doc": "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"}
    )
)
```

Output :

```py
print(df)

         lat       lon         ele                      time
0  60.126749  4.250254  455.735013  2023-08-20T17:42:34.674Z
1  60.126580  4.250247  455.735013  2023-08-20T17:42:36.695Z
2  60.126484  4.250240  455.735013  2023-08-20T17:44:15.112Z
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Will `read_xml` download `http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1` first in order to function? So the code works only when I'm conected to the internet?

Comment: Disconnecting network does not impact execution, you may be confident it does not download the documentation.